# java : create a matrix of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I begin with java and I'm searching for how to create an array 2d of strings :
my array 2d should contains :

```
10 20 "OK"
5  30 "KO"
20 100 "NA"
10 60  "OK"

String[][] matrix = new String[i][j];
for(r=0;i<matrix.length; r++) {
 for (int c=0; c<matrix [r].length; c++) {
     System.out.print("10 " + matrix [r][c]);
 }
```

Comment: So far so good. What is your question?  Do you want to know how to stuff the string values into the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Florin said, but with simplified for-loop:

```
String [][] matrix =  { {"10","20","OK"}, {"5","30","KO"}, {"20","100","NA"}, {"10","60","OK"} };

for (String [] line : matrix) {
    for (String s: line) {
        System.out.print ("10 " + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String[][] matrix = { {"10","20","OK"},{"5","30","KO"}, {"20","100","NA"}, {"10","60","OK"} };
```

Answer (score 1):

All seems good. Maybe you could do a better use of for each loops in java :

```
String[][] matrix = new String[i][j];
for( String[] rows : matrix) {
 for (String row : rows ) {
     System.out.println("10 " + row );
 }
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

What @Jigar said

```
String[][] matrix = { {"10","20","OK"},{"5","30","KO"}, {"20","100","NA"}, {"10","60","OK"} };
```

Plus print:

```
for(r=0;i<matrix.length; r++) {
 for (int c=0; c<matrix [r].length; c++) {
     System.out.print(matrix [r][c] + " ");
 }
 System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions , 3 values for each line ?? and when I type String[][] matrix = { {"test","10","20","OK"},...} it works , where is the problem?